# Is there additional value in having previous versions of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I work in the production team in a petroleum refinery, neither me or anyone i, the department works in IT or software engineering, but we love our VBA macros.

In order to go beyond what one can do with VBA, I started doing some small projects using Visual Studio Express and VB.NET

These projects are getting bigger and bigger, and I am starting to feel limited by VS Express and I am therefore building a business case for a VS Professional licence (my company is too big for Community).

I'll go with a stand-alone licence, since the subscriptions are way overkill for what I do, but even the stand-alone licence is divided in two parts (https://www.visualstudio.com/fr/vs/pricing/).

You can either buy a licence for a fee of $500, or subscribe for $45 a month. Since I plan on using the software for at least a year, the one-time-fee is cheaper, and the only difference between the two is access to older and newer versions. Hence the questions:

- Is the inability to use the pro versions of previous iterations of Visual Studio a big downside? Will I be able to work without big issues?
- Are newer versions a must-have when they come out, or can I sit on VS2017 for a couple years without issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of older versions of visual studio like 2013-2015 depends on projects /solutions that for whatever reason can not be migrated to a newer version of visual studio. In my experience usually companies which do not wish to purchase new licenses. I see no reason why you need the older versions.

As for the newer versions. The main reason I have seen for a visual studio upgrade is the usage of newer .NET versions. A version X of visual studio can only run .NET up till version Y. When version Y+1 of .NET comes out this means if you wish to make use of the new features/changes in .NET Y+1 you would have to upgrade .